# Why component unmounts before a request is performed in React-Flux

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm using React-Flux to build an app. I have a parent component `A`, a child component `B` and another component `C` which is called simultaneously both by `A` and `B`.

The thing is that when `C` is called directly from `A` data is mounted, run and unmounted correctly. When the same component is called from `B`, component is mounted and unmounted, but GET requests are performed after the component unmounts. Why does this happen?

This is the `C` component

```js
class Nameday extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   saints: AppStore.getNames(),
  }
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
 }

 componentWillMount(){
  AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  AppActions.getNames();
 } 
 onChange(){
  this.setState({
   saints: AppStore.getNames(),
  });
 }
 componentWillUnmount(){
  AppStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
 }

 render() {
  let dates = [];
   this.state.saints.map((saint, i) => {
    saint.names.map((name, j) => {
     if (name === firstName) {
      dates.push(saint.date);
     }
     return dates;
    });
    return null;
   });
  let option = ....
  return (
   option
  );
 }
}
```

When the `Nameday` component is called from `B` component, the `onChange` function isn't performed at all.

This is the parent component:

```js
class ParentListItem extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   parent: this.props.parent,
  }
  this.onNamedayChange = this.onNamedayChange.bind(this);
 }

 onNamedayChange(date, id, parent, index){
  let newParent = {
   firstName: this.props.parent.firstName,
   lastName: this.props.parent.lastName,
   phone: this.props.parent.phone,
   email: this.props.parent.email,
   birthday: this.props.parent.birthday,
   nameday: {
    nameday_id: id,
    date: date,
   },
  };
  AppActions.updateParent(this.props.parent._id.$oid, 
   update(this.props.parent, {$merge: newParent}));
  }

  render() {
   const {parent} = this.props;
   return (
    <div>
     <ListGroup>
      <ListGroupItem><img src="images/phone.png" className='glyph' width='35px' role="presentation"/> {parent.phone}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem><img src="images/mail-ru.png" className='glyph' width='35px' role="presentation"/> {parent.email}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem><img src="images/cake-layered.png" className='glyph' width='35px' role="presentation"/> {parent.birthday}</ListGroupItem>

      //this is the component called from both ParentListItem.js and ConnectionListItem.js
      <Nameday name={parent.firstName} callbackNamedayParent={this.onNamedayChange} date={parent.nameday.date} dateId={parent.nameday.nameday_id} onList={true} child={false}/>

     </ListGroup>

     <div>
      //this is the child component
      <ConnectionListItem key={connection.id} connection={connection} index={parent.connections.indexOf(connection)} parent={parent} id={parent._id.$oid} callbackParent={this.onChildChanged}/>
     </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
 }
export default ParentListItem;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the action is fired? console.log in the componentDidMount, in order to see if it really did mount. It could be that the NameDay component had already mounted.

Comment: Yes the action is fired. The sequence of actions that I get is: wil mount, did mount, unmounted and XHR finished loading: GET...

Comment: Something unmounts the component in the code. You need to see what unmounts it. When component C is called from B, does the component C stay in the view, or disappear? Something in the code is unmounting it, and I'm not sure it can be determined from the code u gave us. I thought first that maybe if you return null, the component unmounts. But that shouldn't be the case. Maybe in B you are listening to the same store, and then do not render the component when the store content changes by the action fired by C

Comment: I posted the parent component. The child component `ConnectionListItem` is similar to the parent component and also renders the `Nameday` component. I don't know if there is a race condition issue here, but if I delete the `Nameday` component from the parent the problem still exists. In B I am listening to the same store, yes.